# Flutter pass value through model and function

Tags: flutter

Flutter I need to pass some values and show in a function

This is my model and fucntion

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

import 'dart:io';

import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

import 'package:localstorage/localstorage.dart';


class Cart {
  int id;
  String title;
  String image;
  String price;
  String color;
  String sizeselect;

  Cart({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.image,
    this.price,
    this.color,
    this.sizeselect,

  });



  factory Cart.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) => new Cart(
    id: data["id"],
    title: data["title"],
    image: data["image"],
    price: data["price"],
    color: data["color"],
    sizeselect: data["sizeselect"],

  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "title": title,
    "image": image,
    "price": price,
    "color": color,
    "sizeselect": sizeselect,

  };
}


class AppModel extends Model {

  AppModel() {
    // Create DB Instance & Create Table
    createDatabase();
  }

  createDatabase() async {
    String databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String dbPath = join(databasesPath, 'my.db');

    var database = await openDatabase(dbPath, version: 1, onCreate: populateDb);
    return database;
  }

  void populateDb(Database database, int version) async {
    await database.execute("CREATE TABLE Customer ("
        "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        "title TEXT,"
        "image TEXT,"
        "color TEXT"
        "price TEXT"
        "sizeselect TEXT"
        ")");
  }
    createCustomer(Cart cart)  {
    print('scope');
    print(cart);
      // var result = await database.rawInsert(
      //     "INSERT INTO Customer (id,title, image, color, price, sizeselect)"
      //         " VALUES (${cart.id},${cart.title},${cart.image},${cart
      //         .color},${cart.price},${cart.sizeselect})");
      // return result;
    }

    // Future<List> getCustomers() async {
    //   var result = await database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Customer');
    //   return result.toList();
    // }
  }
```

I am doing like this right now

```
onPressed: () {

    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();

    map['id'] = widget.product.id;
    map['title'] = widget.product.title;
    map['image'] = widget.product.image;
    map['price'] = widget.product.normalPrice;
    map['color'] = selectedColor;
    map['sizeselect'] = selectedSize;
    print(map);
    final Cart cart = Cart.fromJson(map);
    print(cart);
    print(cart);
    AppModel().createCustomer(cart);
    // Model.createCustomer(map);

  }
```

but on function when i print cart its showing `Instance of 'Cart'`  I know i messedup the map things can any one please help how can i pass my values thorugh model or another way ? I need to print the values in my fucntion createCustomer()

Comment: Model you using is right way but when you try to parse json. But if you have simple value then use simple Model class and assign values. eg is given in my ANS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Make model like this:

```
class Cart {
  int id;
  String title;
  String image;
  String price;
  String color;
  String sizeselect;
}
```

And Use like this

```
onPressed: () {

     var cart = Cart();

     cart.id = widget.product.id;
     cart.title = widget.product.title;
     cart.image = widget.product.image;
     cart.price = widget.product.normalPrice;
     cart.color = selectedColor;
     cart.size = selectedSize;
     AppModel().createCustomer(cart); 
 }
```

Comment: But same if i print cart onPressed or on that function its showing Instance of 'Cart' . on print i need to print the products but its showing that instance message

Comment: ah sorry my bad. i need to like cart.id

Answer (score 1):

If you print the variable cart, it will print (Instance of 'Cart').

But try to print the variable with the specific property, for example:

```
print(cart.id);
```

It will print the value of the id an so on with the other properties.